# What's the difference between a "perceptron" and a GLM?

Tags: perceptron

In a comment to [this question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/30037/18652) user nbro comments:

> As a side note, "perceptrons" and "neural networks" may not be the same thing. People usually use the term perceptron to refer to a very simple neural network that has no hidden layer. Maybe you meant the term "multi-layer perceptron" (MLP).

As I understand it, a simple neural network with no hidden layer would simply be a linear model with a non-linearity put on top of it. That sounds exactly like a generalized linear model (GLM), with the non-linearity being the GLM's link function.

Is there a notable difference between (non-multi-layer) perceptrons and GLMs? Or is it simply another case of two equivalent methods having different names from different researchers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The perceptron uses the *Heaviside step* (or *sign*) function as the [activation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function) (so you are not free to use any activation function), while a GLM is a generalization of linear regression, where the *link function* can be, for example, the *logit* (which leads to the *logistic regression*), *identity* function (which leads to *linear regression*), and so on. The sign function has the role in the perceptron as the *sigmoid* in logistic regression.

So, GLM models have a *probabilistic* interpretation (i.e. you assume that the response variable follows some distribution), while perceptrons do not, even though, for example, the perceptron and logistic regression can both be used for classification.